# CSS Hover same for several classes

Tags: css, hover, css-selectors, shorthand

The following classes had exactly the same css rules applied I wonder if the is a way to set those 3 in one.

```
#menuHolder .l1 a:hover
#menuHolder .l2 a:hover
#menuHolder .l3 a:hover
```

So far I tried with no luck:

```
#menuHolder .l1, l2, l3 a:hover
#menuHolder .l1 l2 l3 a:hover
#menuHolder .l1 a:hover, .l2 a:hover, .l3 a:hover
```

Thank you!

Comment: what does your html look like?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to specify the class?

How about just:

```
#menuHolder a:hover{}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#menuHolder .l1 a:hover,
#menuHolder .l2 a:hover,
#menuHolder .l3 a:hover {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#menuHolder .l1 a:hover, #menuHolder .l2 a:hover, #menuHolder .l3 a:hover
{

}
```

If you have classes which will always have the same styles, you can seperate them by commas for the same style set.

However, if this happens often, it might be worth looking into your HTML design to see if it can be tidied up to call the same classes each time.

For example, if `.l1`, `.l2`, `.l3` are the same, perhaps replace the classes with `.l` so that the CSS can just be:

```
#menuHolder .l a:hover
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 #menuHolder .l1 a:hover, #menuHolder .l2 a:hover, #menuHolder .l3 a:hover
 {

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

No. The only way is to:

```
#menuHolder .l1 a:hover, #menuHolder .l2 a:hover, #menuHolder .l3 a:hover {
    ...
}
```

What you should do however, is to give a general class for all 3 of them, and then something like this:

```
#menuHolder .hoverable a:hover {
    ...
}
```